# sqlalchemy relashionship induce join implicitly

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I just read that for making join between tables, we need to define a relationship.

I read it for example in accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6580835/how-to-do-a-join-in-sqlalchemy-session-query).
However, from the documentation [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/join_conditions.html) I found the following quote:

> Configuring how Relationship Joins
>   relationship() will normally create a join between two tables by examining the foreign key relationship between the two tables to determine which columns should be compared.

So now the question I ask myself is:
If I define a relationship, I understand I have an implicit join, so why people are doing another explicit join except the given one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to define a relationship in order to [join](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.join). A [relationship](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship) is between mapped classes, or in other words is an ORM concept; you have objects that have collections of related objects etc. A join is for when you need explicit SQL.

Defining a relationship will not get you an implicit join in the SQL `JOIN` clause sence, as they are lazy by default. You can on the other hand [configure](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html) how the relationship loads related objects and for example use an eager [joinedload](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html#sqlalchemy.orm.joinedload).

As to why someone would use an explicit join even with relationships in place: you cannot perform server side operations like aggregations that require joins with relationships. On the other hand you may not need any of that and be entirely happy with the ORM.

In the answer you linked to a relationship is not required for the join. Joining a target entity (or selectable) just requires there to be a foreign key relationship between the two. For example:

```
In [2]: class A(Base):
   ...:     id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
   ...:     __tablename__ = 'a'
   ...:     

In [4]: class B(Base):
   ...:     id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
   ...:     a_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('a.id'))
   ...:     __tablename__ = 'b'
   ...:     

In [6]: print(session.query(B).join(A))
SELECT b.id AS b_id, b.a_id AS b_a_id 
FROM b JOIN a ON a.id = b.a_id
```

No ORM relationship definitions involved.